# Как сделать плавную анимацию c выезжающим блоком?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытался реализовать анимацию появления блока с правой стороны, получилось почти то что я хотел. Но есть две проблемы.

Во первых анимация срабатывает только при 2 отображении элемента, во вторых анимация не срабатывает на скрытие элемента. Как это все исправить?

```js
$(document).on("click", ".project__discr--active", function () {
//  $(' .modal-dark').removeClass('js-module-hide').show(600, 'swing');
  module();
});



$(document).on("click", ".js-close-modal", function () {
//  $(' .modal-dark').addClass('js-module-hide').hide(600, 'swing');
  module();
});

var box = $('.modal-dark, .modal');
 function module () {
   if (box.hasClass('js-module-hide')) {
    box.removeClass('js-module-hide');
    setTimeout(function () {
      box.removeClass('visuallyhidden');
    }, 20);
  } else {
    box.addClass('visuallyhidden');
    box.one('transitionend', function(e) {
      box.addClass('js-module-hide');
    });
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.project__discr--active {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 2, 45, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.visuallyhidden {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.js-module-hide {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal-dark {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}
.modal.js-module-hide {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.visuallyhidden {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal {
  height: 600px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 120px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  will-change: top;
}
.base {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.close-modal {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
  transition: all ease .3s;
}
.project-gallerey {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
}
.project-info {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project__discr--active">Show me</div>

<div class="modal-dark js-module-hide">
  <div class="modal ">
    <div class="base">
      <div class="close-modal js-close-modal">X</div>
      <div class="project-gallerey">
        <div class="pagination-gallerey"><span class="nav-pengetation on" rel="0"></span><span class="nav-pengetation" rel="1"></span><span class="nav-pengetation" rel="2"></span></div>
        <div class="slider-gallerey">
          <ul class="sliders-wrapper">
            <li class="slider-image slider0"><img src="img/coming-soon.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li class="slider-image slider1"><img src="img/zhHFjKiZ52w.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li class="slider-image slider2"><img src="img/wCobhoyA1To.jpg" alt=""></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-info">
        <div class="main-info">
          <div class="top">
            <div class="date">
              <span class="ng-binding">2013</span>
              <!-- ngIf: current.date.end != null -->
              <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">- 2014</span>
              <!-- end ngIf: current.date.end != null -->
            </div>
            <div class="type-site">desktop website</div>
          </div>
          <div class="sep"></div>
          <div class="info-project__name">New Terracotta</div>
          <div class="tags">
            <!-- ngRepeat: tag in current.tags -->
            <span class="tag-used-skills technologies-in-project__technology">Javascript</span>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: tag in current.tags -->
            <span class="tag-used-skills technologies-in-project__technology">HTML5 &amp; CSS3</span>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: tag in current.tags -->
            <span class="tag-used-skills technologies-in-project__technology">jQUery</span>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: tag in current.tags -->
          </div>
          <ul class="topics">
            <!-- ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- HTML5 &amp; CSS3</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- jQuery</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- oo javascript</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- SEO optimization</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- cross browser compatibility</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- project management</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- DotNetNuke skinning</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возможно, я не до конца понял вашу логику. Но мне показалось, что вы слегка намудрили с классами и напрасно использовали конструкцию

```
var box = $('.modal-dark, .modal');
```

Таким образом, вы выбрали два элемента, родителя и потомка и работали с ним как с одним: проверяли наличие класса, добавляли и убирали классы (одновременно обоим элементам). Когда я навел в этой части порядок, т.е. разделил функции родителя и потомка (родитель просто скрывается, а потомок исполняет анимацию) - все встало на свои места.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".project__discr--active", function () {
//  $(' .modal-dark').removeClass('js-module-hide').show(600, 'swing');
  module();
});



$(document).on("click", ".js-close-modal", function () {
//  $(' .modal-dark').addClass('js-module-hide').hide(600, 'swing');
  module();
});

var box = $('.modal-dark'),
    modal = $('.modal');
function module () {
  if (box.hasClass('js-module-hide')) {
    box.removeClass('js-module-hide');
    setTimeout(function () {
      modal.removeClass('visuallyhidden');
    }, 20);
  } else {
    modal.addClass('visuallyhidden');
    modal.one('transitionend', function(e) {
      box.addClass('js-module-hide');
    });
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.project__discr--active {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 2, 45, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.visuallyhidden {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.js-module-hide {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal-dark {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}
.modal.js-module-hide {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.visuallyhidden {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal {
  height: 600px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 120px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  will-change: top;
}
.base {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.close-modal {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
  transition: all ease .3s;
}
.project-gallerey {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
}
.project-info {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project__discr--active">Show me</div>

<div class="modal-dark js-module-hide">
  <div class="modal visuallyhidden">
    <div class="base">
      <div class="close-modal js-close-modal">X</div>
      <div class="project-gallerey">
        <div class="pagination-gallerey"><span class="nav-pengetation on" rel="0"></span><span class="nav-pengetation" rel="1"></span><span class="nav-pengetation" rel="2"></span></div>
        <div class="slider-gallerey">
          <ul class="sliders-wrapper">
            <li class="slider-image slider0"><img src="img/coming-soon.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li class="slider-image slider1"><img src="img/zhHFjKiZ52w.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li class="slider-image slider2"><img src="img/wCobhoyA1To.jpg" alt=""></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-info">
        <div class="main-info">
          <div class="top">
            <div class="date">
              <span class="ng-binding">2013</span>
              <!-- ngIf: current.date.end != null -->
              <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">- 2014</span>
              <!-- end ngIf: current.date.end != null -->
            </div>
            <div class="type-site">desktop website</div>
          </div>
          <div class="sep"></div>
          <div class="info-project__name">New Terracotta</div>
          <div class="tags">
            <!-- ngRepeat: tag in current.tags -->
            <span class="tag-used-skills technologies-in-project__technology">Javascript</span>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: tag in current.tags -->
            <span class="tag-used-skills technologies-in-project__technology">HTML5 &amp; CSS3</span>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: tag in current.tags -->
            <span class="tag-used-skills technologies-in-project__technology">jQUery</span>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: tag in current.tags -->
          </div>
          <ul class="topics">
            <!-- ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- HTML5 &amp; CSS3</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- jQuery</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- oo javascript</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- SEO optimization</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- cross browser compatibility</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- project management</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
            <li class="project__skills skills-style">- DotNetNuke skinning</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: topic in current.topics -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, запутался немного, спасибо!